# Using stored procedures to generate RDLC report in C#

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, rdlc

I'm making an application that generates reports for my client. I'm using his database that contains stored procedures which return the data needed for the reports. The problem is that I don't know how to execute them from the application (more specific the TableAdapter in my dataset). When I use the visual aid to create the TableAdapter, it shows the error "Invalid object named #table1". This is weird because there is a temporary table called #table1 in the stored procedure. 
When I try to do the whole job programmatically, I get the exception 
`Incorrect syntax near '.'.
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.`
I created a DataTable that has identical structure as the result of the stored procedure, but I still get the same exception

I added the `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`, and have a new exception `No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRow[] to a known managed provider native type.`

Comment: The code of the stored procedure (no, it contains some personal data that I am not allowed to share) or the code that I use in my application?

Comment: just change the column name and the table name then paste it here :)

Comment: I've edited the question, I made some progress, but I still can't get the result (i triggered the stored procedure, but I get the mentioned exception)

Answer (score 0):

TableAdapter tries to guess the columns of the result set by using [SET FMTONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) (or a similar mechanism) which does not recognize #temp tables.

Can you replace the #temp table with a [@table variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) ?